# Package does not exist when import kotlin class into java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm sorry if I'm asking a basic question, but I'm new to android app programming.
I have a class written in kotlin along the following path: `package com.albs.calendar`
And a class written in Java along the following path: `package com.albs.ui.gallery;`

I'm trying to import kotlin into java (`import com.albs.calendar.Example5Fragment;`), but at the build stage I get the following error:

```
error: package com.albs.calendar does not exist
import com.albs.calendar.Example5Fragment;
```

Here is the code of Example5Fragment:

```
package com.albs.calendar

class Example5Fragment : BaseFragment(R.layout.example_5_fragment), HasToolbar {

    override val toolbar: Toolbar?
        get() = null

    override val titleRes: Int = R.string.example_5_title

    private var selectedDate: LocalDate? = null
    private val monthTitleFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM")

    private val flightsAdapter = Example5FlightsAdapter()
    private val flights = generateFlights().groupBy { it.time.toLocalDate() }

    private lateinit var binding: Example5FragmentBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = Example5FragmentBinding.bind(view)
        ...

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
//        requireActivity().window.statusBarColor = requireContext().getColorCompat(R.color.example_5_toolbar_color)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
//        requireActivity().window.statusBarColor = requireContext().getColorCompat(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    }

    private fun updateAdapterForDate(date: LocalDate?) {
        flightsAdapter.flights.clear()
        flightsAdapter.flights.addAll(flights[date].orEmpty())
        flightsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

UPD [image]

UPD2 The problem was solved by creating a new project and moving the code there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android studio, just create an object or make a call to that class. like this...[image: example]

So, now I want to select the vote contract delegate and then enter.

Android studio would automatically import it.

Just look at the package name at the right section and select the correct one.

This works for both kotlin and java.

You don't ever have to import it manually.

IDEs nowadays are smart enough to suggest that for you.

Comment: I have another problem. Android studio automatically imports com.albs.calendar.Example5Fragment; but at the build stage it gave the error that I described above. Attach image with import to original post

Comment: did you change the package name inside a file or something?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything with the filename. Maybe I'm missing dependencies, but I can't figure out which ones...